# Passing JSON data array in cfhttpparam's value

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am trying to pass the JSON data in the value of `cfhttpparam` as follows:

```
Line #95: <cfhttpparam type="formfield" 
name="seriesofdata" 
value="[{"Id": 118,"Value": 1,"Desc": "Checking Description ","Group": 1}]"/>
```

But I keep on getting the following error:

```
Invalid token " found on line 95 at column XX.
```

I have checked the JSON and it's valid JSON that I am passing as a value.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So this is certainly valid JSON:

```
{"Id": 118,"Value": 1,"Desc": "Checking Description ","Group": 1}
```

However you're wrapping it inside `" "` so the first `"` in your JSON packet will look like a closing `"` to the cfhttpparam value

```
<cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="seriesofdata" value="[{"Id": 118,"Value": 1,"Desc": "Checking Description ","Group": 1}]"/>
                                                           ^
```

Looks to CF like you're doing:

```
<cfhttpparam 
    type="formfield" 
    name="seriesofdata" 
    value="[{"
    Id": 118,"Value": 1,"Desc": "Checking Description ","Group": 1}]"
/>
```

That whole last bit just looks like garbage, hence the 'Invalid token' error.

Just either escape those " or use single-quotes instead, either in the JSON or in the CFML.

```
<cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="seriesofdata" value='[{"Id": 118,"Value": 1,"Desc": "Checking Description ","Group": 1}]'>
```